# Is it possible to pop the camera on the iPad 2 inside of a UIPopoverController using presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to pop the camera (using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) on the iPad 2 inside of a UIPopoverController using presentModalViewController?

Whenever I do it the camera just goes full screen. I need it inside of the UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work by calling `presentModalViewController:animated:`. To make the camera show up in a UIPopoverController's UI, then you want something similar to the following:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;   

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                 initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:launchCameraButton
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
```

There is another way to launch the popover from an arbitrary spot in your UI also. The docs should explain that.